# HttpContext.SignInAsync when using ITicketStore to manage Cookies with db calls RenewAsync Instead of StoreAsync On login

Tags: .net-core

Using a ITicketStore for cookie management like this https://ml-software.ch/posts/implementing-a-custom-iticketstore-for-asp-net-core-identity

And having a cookie with `AllowRefresh=false`, `IsPersistent=true` and the expire time to 1 year.

With the login being hit once the `StoreAsync` method is called but login again and `RenewAsync` is called instead. Which causes issues because on login the user's session managed in the db is removed and the new cookie sent to the user is now invalid because there is no user session in the db. There is a particular reason for this setup.

The question needing answered is why or how is `RenewAsync` being called on repeat login calls. Instead of `StoreAsync`.

Comment: Did you solve this by any chance ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @AshikAhmed probably not the right solution but I put `await StoreAsync(ticket)` as the only line in `RenewAsync`

Answer (score 1):

just call the renew method in store,

```
public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var key = KeyPrefix + guid.ToString();
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }
```

Comment: did you mean method? :-)

Comment: yes :-) it is just typing mistake  (method** )